# PATCH request with form-date c#

Tags: c#, json, patch, webapi

In my web application I need to implement PATCH API endpoint to update/patch some entity.
I Know JSON Patch is something I can implement ,but problem here that the data from front end is in **From-data** format .Is there any way we can implement JsonPatch type process in form data for patch calls??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: As of now i am getting complete data request  in form -data format 
like

[HttpPatch("myController")]
public CustomResponseDTO Update([FromForm] customDataRequestDTO reqDto)

but i want to implement json patch type implementation with form data .

Comment: Please, add your actual code to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPatch("update")]
public Person Patch([FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<Person> personPatch)
{
        personPatch.ApplyTo(_defaultPerson);
        return _defaultPerson;
}
```

You need to change some configuration below link help to you

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I have to use [FromForm] here instead of [FromBody] ,can i use it?

Comment: are you tried [FromBody] instead of [FormForm] just try it. and also refer the link